# Defining white noise intensites in state space kalman filter with spectral factorization

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, kalman-filter, noise

I'm a noob on this subject, so please be extra *clear* :)

With a system of equations:
$$\dot\omega_x = \alpha_s\omega_y - \epsilon\omega_s\omega_y + \epsilon\omega_s\eta + Q_x$$
$$\dot\omega_y = -\frac{\alpha_s}{1-\epsilon}\omega_x -\frac{\epsilon\gamma}{1-\epsilon}\omega_y +\frac{\epsilon\gamma}{1-\epsilon}\eta -\frac{\epsilon\beta}{1-\epsilon}e_m +\frac{Q_y}{1-\epsilon}$$
$$\dot\eta = \gamma\omega_y - \gamma\eta +\beta e_m$$
$$y(t)=\omega_x + n$$
where $Q_x$ and $Q_y$ are plant momentum disturbances, with $$\phi_{Q_x}(w) = \phi_{Q_y}(w)= \frac{0.05}{(\frac{w}{10^5})+1}$$
and n is output noise
$$\phi_n(w) = 0.625$$
I have been asked to design a discrete time kalman filter, and given the guidance in form of general steps. It is as the first of these steps I fail. $$$$

"Start to convert all the disturbances into white noise. You need to perform Spectral factorization. And define the noise with intensities $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_{12}$"
$$$$It has previously been seen that $$R=[\matrix{R_1& R_{12}\\ R^T_{12}& R_2}].$$

I have gone over the litterature and can't seem to understand what I should do.
What I have tried is:

**Spectral factorization**

We wish to find $G_v(w)$ such that $\phi_{Q_x}(w) = |G_v(jw)|^2$, which I have found to be $G_v(jw)=\frac{\sqrt{5}\cdot10^4}{10^5+jw}$. From what I have read we would have noise $v=[v_1 v_2]^T$ with intensity $R$.

Theory shows it like this:

A process is given by $$\dot{x} = Ax+Bu+Nv_1$$
$$y=Cx + Du+ v_2$$
where $v = [\matrix{v_1 \\v_2}]$ is white noise with $R_0 = [\matrix{R_1& R_{12}\\ R^T_{12}& R_2}]$

I simply see the path to $R_1$, $R_2$, and $R_{12}$.

*It is related to a course on Space Craft control.*

<strike>**Edit**</strike>

Additional attempt. From further diving I have found that
$$R=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int^\infty_{-\infty} |G(j\omega)|^2 d\omega$$
$$|G(j\omega)|^2 = \phi_{Q}(w)$$
$$R=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{0.05}{(\frac{w}{10^5})+1} d\omega$$
$$R=\{integrating\}=2500$$
If we define $R_{12}$ as $0$, then $R=R_1 + R_2$, which is allows us to select $R_1$ and $R_2$ as desired, for example $R_1 = R_2 = \frac{1}{2}R=1250$. However I do not see how you should include $n$ in this - or how to construct the approporate matrix for dealing with $Q_x$, $Q_y$ **and** $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what the correct solution is for this problem. First I had missunderstood what $R_1$ was. $R_1$ should be the the $R$ the the equation below, and their purpuse.

In this scenario we have $\phi(w) = G_v(jw) R G_v^*(jw)$  where $\phi$, $R$ and $G_v$ are vectors / matricies.

If we say that $\phi(w) = \left[\matrix{\phi_x &0\\ 0& \phi_y} \right]$,
$R=$$\left[\matrix{A& B\\ C& D}\right] = R_1$, $G_v = \left[\matrix{G_v(jw)& 0\\ 0& G_v(jw)}\right]$, $G_v^* = \left[\matrix{G_v^*(jw)& 0\\ 0& G_v^*(jw)}\right]$

(Re-call) $\phi_x = \phi_y = \phi$. We find that
$$ \phi(w) = \left[\matrix{\phi &0\\ 0& \phi} \right] = \left[\matrix{A\cdot G_v \cdot G_v^*& B\cdot G_v \cdot G_v^*\\ C\cdot G_v \cdot G_v^*& D\cdot G_v \cdot G_v^*}\right] = \left[\matrix{A \phi& B \phi\\ C \phi& D \phi}\right],$$ this reveals that $A = D = 1$, $B = C = 0$, thous $R_1 = \left[\matrix{1& 0\\ 0& 1}\right]$. As for $R_2$ is should simply be $\phi_n = 0.625$, as it is a constant and one dimensional.

The noise can be modeld as white noise passing through a system, in this case described by $G_v$.

White noise $\cdot$ $G_v$ --> noise.

Converting the Transfer function TF to state space form we get:
$$A_w = \left[\matrix{-10^5& 0\\ 0& -10^5}\right]$$
$$B_w = \left[\matrix{1& 0\\ 0& 1}\right]$$
$$C_w = \left[\matrix{\sqrt{0.05}& 0\\ 0& \sqrt{0.05}}\right].$$ Which can be used to represent the noise. The noise is thus modeled by construction the system / TF that shapes a white noise input to our noise.

*$R_1$,$R_2$, and $R_{12}$ are later in this project used to check assumptions for controllability and observability of the system.*